# Angular JS does not allow preventDefault or return false to work on form submission

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, http-post

I have a form I'd like to deliver via AJAX :

```
<form class="form-inline ng-pristine" ng-submit="sendForm()" method="post" action="/sign_up" accept-charset="UTF-8">

$scope.sendForm = (e) ->
  e.preventDefault ->
  console.log 'sendForm()'
  return false
```

The `console.log` appears, and immediately it delivers the form.

It ignores both the `e.preventDefault()`, and the `return false`.

AngularJS reminds me of the honey badger. It just doesn't care.

Comment: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngSubmit, Check the doc, This does prevent the default action.

Comment: +1 for honey badger reference... ;-)

Answer (score 54):

I know I am pretty late to the party, but in case you did not figure it out yet, you can keep the action and make sure the form is not actually submitted by passing `$event` to the `ng-submit` function. Then you can use `event.preventDefault();` in your controller after you do all your processing.

So in your case it would be:

```
<form class="form-inline ng-pristine" ng-submit="sendForm($event)" method="post" action="/sign_up" accept-charset="UTF-8">

$scope.sendForm = (e) ->
  // doing stuff
  e.preventDefault()
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is unfortunately not an option with older versions: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/3619

Comment: This is the best option, and most correct. Angular let you decide witch parameters you want to pass to your function, this provides you with more flexibility

Comment: Your answer is better because it works even without JS. Prog enhancement ftw

Answer (score 44):

Well, you're not doing it the "Angular way". Angular provides a directive called ng-submit, which does that preventDefault for you **(as long as you don't have an action attribute specified on your form)**.

Markup (with validation!)

```
<form name="myForm" ng-submit="sendForm()">
  <div>
    <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="data.name" required/>
    <span ng-show="myForm.name.$error.required && myForm.name.$dirty">required</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="email" name="email" ng-model="data.email" required/>
    <span ng-show="myForm.name.$error.required && myForm.name.$dirty">required</span>
    <span ng-show="myForm.name.$error.email && myForm.name.$dirty">invalid email</span>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Code

```
app.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.sendForm = function (){
       $http.post('/Submit/To/Url', $scope.data).success(function(data) {
           alert('done!');
       });
    };
});
```

Comment: Nope, this doesn't preventDefault

Comment: Take the action="" attribute off of your form. If there is an action specified, it will not preventDefault.

Comment: Ahhhh that was it. Kinda limiting, but I'll accept. Thanks Blesh!

Comment: Surely removing the action attribute is extremely bad practice for forms? Is there no way Angular can work with standard HTML forms or does it require rewriting the form parameters?

Comment: You can also get the event like so:

`<form ng-submit="doThing($event)">`

Comment: @bioball ... you can, but I'd recommend against that as you'll start to see the DOM creep into your controller via the Event object, which is a DOM-specific thing.

Comment: If you want to keep the DOM away from your controllers, you can do: ng-submit="$event.preventDefault();sendForm()". Or you can make a custom directive that will attach to the form's submit event, preventDefaut on it and call the specified method.

Comment: As your question is kinda of a reference would be very nice if you could edit it to show the progressive way of binding to ng-submit.. You could just setup a normal form (with action & method). Add angularjs stuff (ng-submit) and add $event.preventDefault(). That way works both with and without JS.

Answer (score 5):

You can get the event by passing `$event` into your ng-click or ng-submit. It's like dependency injection, except in your expressions.

html

```
<form class="form-inline ng-pristine" ng-submit="sendForm($event)" method="post" action="/sign_up" accept-charset="UTF-8">
```

coffeescript

```
$scope.sendForm = (e) ->
  e.preventDefault()
  console.log 'sendForm()'
  false
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a better solution of all of the other answers.

Let suppose you have html5 validation required attribute attached to form elements.

Now

```
<button ng-submit="Save($event)">SEND ME</button>
```

And now you function

```
$scope.Save = function($event){

    $event.preventDefault();
    .
    . // may be an ajax request
    .

    return false;
}
```

This will not only trigger html5 validation but also this will prevent form submission redirect.

Comment: This does not work for me due to `$event` being undefined.

Answer (score 2):

Other way to solve this is with a directives.

```
app.directive("submit", [function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            submit: "="
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
            element.bind("submit", function (loadEvent) {
                return scope.submit(loadEvent);
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

---

```
<form submit="sendForm" method="post" action="/sign_up">
```

---

```
$scope.sendForm = function(e) {
  if ($scope.whatever)
      return true;
  else
      return false;
};
```