# question mark added in middle of url on form submit

Tags: angularjs

When I click the submit button in a form it is adding a ? right before the # so /app/#/pageName changes into /app/?#/pageName. Is this normal behavior? Code is just basic stuff.

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.submit = function() {

    };
});

<form ng-controller="MyCtrl" ng-submit="submit()">
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: can you add the submit function?

Comment: The submit function is on there. It's just empty. I took out the code that submits to my server because it's irrelevant. It does the same thing with or without it.

Comment: Did you try to remove `action` attribute from your form?

Comment: there was no action attribute

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I finally found the answer thanks to [Angular JS does not allow preventDefault or return false to work on form submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14524020/angular-js-does-not-allow-preventdefault-or-return-false-to-work-on-form-submiss).

in my `ng-submit` I had to add `$event` as parameter which passed the event to my submit function and I was then able to do `event.preventDefault()` to prevent the route from changing. Not sure if this is a bug in angular or if it's intended behaviour but hopefully this will help someone else.

So here is the fixed code:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.submit = function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    };
});

<form ng-controller="MyCtrl" ng-submit="submit($event)">
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you <3 . Pesky question mark. Angular should address this.