# Angular-JS Question Mark before Pound in URL?

Tags: angularjs

Why is there a question mark before the pound symbol in this Anuglar URL?

```
http://localhost:4000/apps/entrance/?#/orders
```

I cannot find any logical reason for this.

Comment: what is your route configuration? When and where do you see this url?

Comment: Are you perhaps clicking submit on a form? See this SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25937962/question-mark-added-in-middle-of-url-on-form-submit. Apparently submitting a form can do this.

Answer (score 0):

using `$locationProvider.hashPrefix` method you can set prefix to the #. check this configuration in your app.

```
var app = angular.module("MyApp", [])
.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
});
```

[$locationProvider docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$locationProvider)

Answer (score 0):

If in the previous html page form is there, then by default it acts as get method. By removing form we can achieve that.