# Where is the question mark coming from in Angular URL?

Tags: angularjs, express, satellizer

I'm losing my mind trying to find the thing placing the question mark in my URL?  It's not there when I'm navigating.  But it appears as soon as I try to hit the back end (using Satellizer):

**Before the Call**
http://localhost:3000/#/

**After the Call**
http://localhost:3000/?#/

Comment: Does [this help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25937962/question-mark-added-in-middle-of-url-on-form-submit)? Do you have a form with an action="#" somewhere? I've seen issues where that causes a weird crash/digest/recycle of the page.

Comment: @G Deward did you find out a solution for your problem?

Comment: @divine I ended up getting by it, but don't recall how.

Comment: @G.Deward i got the answer for that