# angular form validation issue- angular validation is not happening

Tags: angularjs

My form is as shown below. But on click of submit button the form is submitting with out validation...I am using spring security so xhr call won't allow to redirect on another page from server(so I have to give the url in action). If I remove "novalidate" page is taking default html validation

```html
<form name="loginForm" id="loginForm" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/j_spring_security_check" novalidate>
  <div class="panel-body">
   <div class="form-group has-feedback">
    <input type="email" name="j_username" ng-model="j_username"
     class="form-control placeholder-color" placeholder="Email"
     ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$/"
     required autocomplete="off" />
    <div class="form-devider"></div>
    <div ng-messages="loginForm.j_username.$error"
     ng-if="loginForm.$submitted">
     <div class="has-error" ng-message="required">
      <spring:message code="peak.email.required" />
     </div>
     <div class="has-error" ng-message="pattern">
      <spring:message code="peak.enter.valid.email" />
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group has-feedback">
    <input type="password" name="j_password" id="j_password"
     placeholder="Password" class="form-control placeholder-color"
     ng-model="j_password" required autocomplete="off" /> <%-- <input
     type="hidden" name="url" id="url" placeholder="Password"
     ng-model="link"
     ng-init="link='${pageContext.request.contextPath}/j_spring_security_check'" /> --%>
    <div class="form-devider"></div>
    <div ng-messages="loginForm.j_password.$error"
     ng-if="loginForm.$submitted">
     <div class="has-error" ng-message="required">
      <spring:message code="peak.password.required" />
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div id="login-error-box1" style="display: none"></div>
  <button type="submit"
   class="btn btn-block custome-btn-orange pbi-mt15">
   <spring:message code="peak.login" />
  </button>
 </form>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: See this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14524020/angular-js-does-not-allow-preventdefault-or-return-false-to-work-on-form-submiss/22443139#22443139.

Comment: You need to have an ng-submit and stop it from posting your form if it's invalid.

Comment: my form is action specified, so how can i use ng-submit?

Comment: Like this : <form class="form-inline ng-pristine" ng-submit="sendForm($event)" method="post" action="/sign_up" accept-charset="UTF-8">

$scope.sendForm = (e) ->
  // doing stuff
  e.preventDefault()

Comment: See the answers to the link i shared.

Comment: Sorry  to bother you curiousgeek. Iam very new in angularjs ...I added the same but it is still showing the default html validation with toottip> what I did is I craeted a conroller and called the $scope.sendForm = function(e){
    // doing stuff
       console.log("sds");
      e.preventDefault();
   } inside that

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this plnkr : http://plnkr.co/edit/rZaKXEp7vspvEerFtVH8?p=preview

```
$scope.validate = function(isValid,$event){
      console.log(isValid);
      console.log($scope.loginForm);
      if(!isValid){
        $event.preventDefault();
      }
    }
```

You need to create an angular controller with a function to run on ng-submit. That function will look for if form is invalid and stops it from posting the form.
which allows you to see your error messages.

Comment: Thanks fro the replay. I just want to see the error message on submit button click. I changed the plunker like this but nothing is coming... http://plnkr.co/edit/kH9znu?p=preview

Comment: loginForm.$submitted will always be false, as you are preventing the action. Instead declare a variable on scope called $scope.isSubmitted and set it to true in the controller method for validate. Use that in variable in your ng-if condition.