# ng-click refreshes the page instead of submit

Tags: angularjs, jersey

Hi i have an angular web form which takes input from the user and inserts into the database.I am using jersey-jackson rest web services and hibernate.But when i try to submit the form,the previous page which had the hyperlink to the current page is refreshed and the current page is reloaded again(Loading of previous page is seen in the network log).The url specified in the http request is not even invoked.Following is my code

```html
<div id="main">
  <h1>Create Leave</h1>
    <form class="form-horizontal" ng-controller="MyAddController" >
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="employeeName" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Employee Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input type="text" id="num" class="form-control" ng-model="num" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3"></div>

        </div>
        
           <div class="form-group">
            <label for="leaveType" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Leave Type</label>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <select id="leaveType" class="form-control" ng-model="leaveType">
                    <option value="">Hospital</option>
                    <option value="female">leave type 2</option>
                     <option value="female">leave type 3</option>
                      <option value="female">leave type 4</option>
                       <option value="female">leave type 5</option>
                        <option value="female">leave type 6</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-7"></div>
        </div>
       
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="leaveStartDate" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Leave Start Date</label>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <input type="date" id="startDates" class="form-control" ng-model="startDate" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-7"></div>
        </div>
       
         <div class="form-group">
            <label for="leaveEndDate" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Leave End Date</label>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <input type="date" id="endDate" class="form-control" ng-model="endDate" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-7"></div>
        </div>
        
     
        
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <span><b>Is Half Day leave</b></span>
                <div class="radio">
                    <label><input value="Yes" type="radio" name="halfDay" ng-model="isHalfDay" />Yes</label>
                </div>
                <div class="radio">
                    <label><input value="No" type="radio" name="halfDay" ng-model="isHalfDay" />No</label>
                </div>
            </div>
          
        </div>

        <input type="submit" value="Save" ng-click='add();' class="btn btn-primary col-sm-offset-3" /> 
        <input type="reset" value="Reset" ng-click="resetForm()" class="btn" /> <br/>
  
   </form>
   
  <script>
 function MyAddController($scope, $http) {
  $scope.add = function() {
   $http.get("webapi/blog/create", {
    params : {
     
     signum : $scope.num,
     leaveType : $scope.leaveType,
     startDate : $scope.startDate,
     endDate : $scope.endDate,
     isHalfDay : $scope.isHalfDay
    }
   }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    if (data) {
     $scope.data = data;
     alert("success")
    }
   }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    alert("error");
   })
  }

 }
</script>
```

and the bean class

```html
package com.king.entity;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class LeaveDetails {
 
 @Id
 private String num;
 public String getnum() {
  return num;
 }
 public void setnum(String num) {
  this.num = num;
 }
 public String getLeaveType() {
  return leaveType;
 }
 public void setLeaveType(String leaveType) {
  this.leaveType = leaveType;
 }
 public Date getStartdate() {
  return startdate;
 }
 public void setStartdate(Date startdate) {
  this.startdate = startdate;
 }
 public Date getEndDate() {
  return endDate;
 }
 public void setEndDate(Date endDate) {
  this.endDate = endDate;
 }
 public String getIsHalfDay() {
  return isHalfDay;
 }
 public void setIsHalfDay(String isHalfDay) {
  this.isHalfDay = isHalfDay;
 }
 private String leaveType;
 private Date startdate;
 private Date endDate;
 private String isHalfDay;
 
 
 

}
```

DAO

```html
package com.king.dao;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;

import com.king.entity.Blog;
import com.king.entity.LeaveDetails;
import com.king.test.HibernateTest;

public class AddLeaveDao {
 
 public void addDetails(LeaveDetails data) {
  Session session = HibernateTest.getSession();
  Transaction ts = session.beginTransaction();
  session.saveOrUpdate(data);
  session.flush();
  ts.commit();
  session.close();
 }
```

and the WS

```html
package com.king.webapi;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.BeanParam;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;

import com.king.dao.AddLeaveDao;
import com.king.dao.BlogDao;
import com.king.dao.LeaveDao;
import com.king.entity.Blog;
import com.king.entity.LeaveBalance;
//import com.king.entity.Love;
import com.king.entity.LeaveDetails;

@Path("/blog")
public class BlogWS {

 @GET
 @Path("list")
 @Produces({ "application/json" })
 public List<LeaveBalance> list() {
  List l= new LeaveDao().getAllLeaves();
  Iterator i=l.iterator();
  while(i.hasNext())
  {
   LeaveBalance m=(LeaveBalance)i.next();
   System.out.println(m.getLeaveBalance());
  }
  
  return l;
 }

 @GET
 @Path("create")
 @Produces({ "application/json" })
 public String create(@BeanParam LeaveDetails ld) {
  System.out.println("Entered here");
  new AddLeaveDao().addDetails(ld);
  System.out.println("Returned  here");
  return "{}";
 }

 @GET
 @Path("findById")
 @Produces({ "application/json" })
 public Blog findById(@QueryParam("id") String id) {
  return new BlogDao().findBlogById(id);
 }

 @GET
 @Path("update")
 @Produces({ "application/json" })
 public String update(@BeanParam Blog blog) {
  new BlogDao().updateBlog(blog);
  return "{}";
 }
}
```

edit:actual js i am using

```html
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.calendar','ui.router']);
app.controller('myNgController', ['$scope', '$http', 'uiCalendarConfig', function ($scope, $http, uiCalendarConfig) {
    
    $scope.SelectedEvent = null;
    var isFirstTime = true;
 
    $scope.events = [];
    $scope.eventSources = [$scope.events];
    $scope.events.push({
        title: "Leave",
        description: "jahsojoaisjjoijaso",
        start: new Date("2017-05-03"),
        end: new Date("2017-05-03"),
        allDay : false,
        stick: false
    });
 
 
    /*//Load events from server
    $http.get('/home/getevents', {
        cache: true,
        params: {}
    }).then(function (data) {
        $scope.events.slice(0, $scope.events.length);
        angular.forEach(data.data, function (value) {
         
        });
    });*/
 
    //configure calendar
    $scope.uiConfig = {
        calendar: {
            height: 450,
            editable: false,
            displayEventTime: false,
            header: {
                left: 'month basicWeek basicDay agendaWeek agendaDay',
                center: 'title',
                right:'today prev,next'
            },
            eventClick: function (event) {
                $scope.SelectedEvent = event;
            },
            eventAfterAllRender: function () {
                if ($scope.events.length > 0 && isFirstTime) {
                    //Focus first event
                    uiCalendarConfig.calendars.myCalendar.fullCalendar('gotoDate', $scope.events[0].start);
                    isFirstTime = false;
                }
            }
        }
    };
 
}]);

app.controller("MyDbController",function ($scope, $http) {
 //$scope.data = [{title: 'welcome hello'},{title: 'great testing'}];

 $http.get("webapi/blog/list", {}).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
  $scope.data = data;
 }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
  alert("error");
 })
});
app.controller("MyAddController",function ($scope, $http) {
 $scope.add = function() {
 $http.get("webapi/blog/create", {
  params : {
   signum : $scope.num,
   leaveType : $scope.leaveType,
   startDate : $scope.startDate,
   endDate : $scope.endDate,
   isHalfDay : $scope.isHalfDay
   
  }
 }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
  if (data) {
   $scope.data = data;
   alert("success");
  }
 }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
  alert("error");
 })
 }
});

app.config(function($stateProvider){
 $stateProvider
 .state("applyLeave",{
  url:"/applyLeave",
  templateUrl:"html/LeaveApply.html",
  controller:"leaveController",
  controllerAs:"leaveController"
 });
 v.controller("leaveController",function($scope)
   {
  
   })
});
```

When i click on save this is the url pattern shown in the browser. http://localhost:8081/hibernate-jersey-angularjs/?halfDay=No#/applyLeave .I dont understand why

Please help

Comment: why you use `get` to create and also your entity fields not match with the json data that you send from ajax.

Comment: +Hadi ..Dint quite follow what you just said.I am a beginner ..Please let me know what is the problem

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to fix this is to remove `type="submit"` from your button that calls the add() method, replacing it with `type="button"`

```
 <input type="button" value="Save" ng-click='add()' class="btn btn-primary col-sm-offset-3" />
```

Otherwise, you need to add `ng-submit="add()"` on your form, and then remove the `ng-click="add()"` from your button with type=submit.

Your form should look like this:

```
 <form class="form-horizontal" ng-controller="MyAddController" ng-submit="add()">
```

And your button like this:

```
<input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-offset-3" />
```

Either of these should work.

By the way, you don't need to use ; at the end of an ng-click instruction. Also, try using the button tag instead of input for the save **button**.

EDIT: You forgot to declare the app to use in your html. On the body of your HTML code, use `ng-app='myApp'`

Comment: tried        <input type="button" value="Save" ng-click='add();' class="btn btn-primary col-sm-offset-3" /> without changing anything in the page.The button click doesnt do anything.and  <form class="form-horizontal" ng-controller="MyAddController" ng-submit="add()"> gives same problem

Comment: Take a look at [the answer for this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14524020/angular-js-does-not-allow-preventdefault-or-return-false-to-work-on-form-submiss)

Comment: @vikk, did you create a module for your controller? Take a look at the documentation for how angular works here: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller

Comment: updated my question..when i click on submit this is the url pattern shown in the browser " http://localhost:8081/hibernate-jersey-angularjs/?halfDay=No#/applyLeave "..I dont understand why

Comment: @vikk, you forgot to declare the app to use in your html. Use ng-app='myApp' on the body of your HTML.

Comment: actually this page comes in the ui-view after routing from the ui-router.I have declared ng-model in the main body tag,isnt that enough.

Comment: ngModel binds an input , select , textarea (or custom form control) to a property on the scope. In your MAIN html file, the one that holds the ui router template, you need to specify the app module that the HTML file should use. In your case, myApp

Comment: yeah that i have done by using <body ng-app="myApp">content</body>